# Can I install Visual Studio 2010 SP1 SDK with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: sdk, visual-studio-2012

I need Visual Studio 2010 SP1 SDK to build this project: https://github.com/abb-iss/SrcML.NET/tree/master/ABB.SrcML

But I only have Visual Studio 2012 (ultimate edition) and its SDK installed, I was wondering if is possible to install the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 SDK without having to install Visual Studio 2010 or maybe can I convert the project to use VS 2012 SDK instead

Answer (score 0):

You can't install VS2010 SDK over VS2012 but in most cases you can convert the VS2010 to VS2012.